# is it possible to implement "define-macro" in mit-scheme

Tags: scheme, mit-scheme

After reading [this page](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/dorai/t-y-scheme/t-y-scheme-Z-H-20.html#node_sec_A.3). I find it hard to memorize how to use `define-syntax` in place of `define-macro`, so I want to implement `define-macro` (or at least find some equivalent) in mit-scheme.

Here is my (problematic) implementation:

```
(define-syntax define-macro
  (rsc-macro-transformer
    (let ((xfmr (lambda (macro-name macro-body)
      (list 'define-syntax macro-name
        (list 'rsc-macro-transformer
          (let ((m-xfmr macro-body))
            (lambda (e r)
              (apply m-xfmr (cdr e)))))))))
      (lambda (e r)
        (apply xfmr (cdr e))))))

(define-macro my-when
  (lambda (test . branch)
    (list 'if test (cons 'begin branch))))

(my-when #t
  (begin
    (display "True")
    (newline)))
```

And the REPL complained:

```
;The object (lambda (test . branch) (list (quote if) test (cons (quote begin) branch))) is not applicable.
```

I'm new to scheme and have no idea about what is wrong, can someone help me out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, you should learn to use quasiquotation, so your macro is easier to read. Like this:

```
(define-macro (my-when test . branch)
  `(if ,test
     (begin ,@branch)))
```

More seriously, though, this is pretty easy to write using `syntax-rules`, and you really should vastly prefer it over `define-macro`.

```
(define-syntax-rule (my-when test branch ...)
  (if test
    (begin branch ...)))
```

Oh, you haven't seen `define-syntax-rule` before? It's a simple macro you can use for writing a one-clause `define-syntax` macro, and it's defined so:

```
(define-syntax define-syntax-rule
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((define-syntax-rule (name . pattern) template)
     (define-syntax name
       (syntax-rules ()
         ((name . pattern) template))))))
```

Notice how, using `define-syntax-rule`, simple macros become really, really easy to write. Here's another example:

```
(define-syntax-rule (let ((name value) ...)
                      expr ...)
  ((lambda (name ...)
     expr ...)
   value ...))
```

Comment: +1, especially to the advice to simply use syntax-rules.  It's hygienic, which can save you from having to debug some really hideous bugs later on.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't heard of `define-syntax-rule` before. It does simplify the code. But here I encountered a problem: when I attempted to eval `(define-syntax-rule (my-when test branch) (if test (begin branch)))`, it said `;Unbound variable: test`. BTW, my scheme version is mit-scheme 9.0.1

Comment: @Javran Did you run the `(define-syntax define-syntax-rule ...)` thing I pasted? You need to do that first.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it had already been defined. Now it works, thank you in advance!

Comment: @Javran In some Scheme implementations, like Racket and Guile, it's already defined. In MIT Scheme, I guess that's not the case. :-) Anyway, glad that helped. :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you really need define-macro semantics, you can get a reasonable approximation in mit-scheme like so:

```
(define-syntax define-macro
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((define-macro (name . args) body ...)
     (define-syntax name
       (rsc-macro-transformer
         (let ((transformer (lambda args body ...)))
           (lambda (exp env)
              (apply transformer (cdr exp)))))))))
```

You could then define my-when as:

```
(define-macro (my-when test . branch)
  `(if ,test (begin ,@branch)))
```